# Using mysql triggers to update fields part of a composite primary key

Tags: mysql, triggers, composite-primary-key

I'm new to mysql triggers and I'm trying to figure it out how should a trigger be created for the following case.

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `trigger` (
  `group` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group`,`order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is how the table would look with some sample data:
[image]

The trigger that I want to create should make sure that, for each new record added with a given group, the order field is updated with the correct order index.

So, if I were to add a new record with the group 1, the order field will be automatically be updated to the next order which, for the given example would be 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statements inside a trigger should do the trick.

```
DECLARE neworder INTEGER;
SELECT max(`order`) + 1 INTO neworder FROM `trigger` WHERE `group` = NEW.`group`;
SET NEW.`order` = neworder;
```

BTW, it's not a great idea to use reserved words for table or column names.
You might want to reconsider your naming scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer Johan, however, there seems to be a problem. The trigger works for the the group columns that were already populated into the table but when a new group value is added I get a "Column 'order' cannot be null" mySQL error.

Comment: The problem was due to the fact than the neworder select query was not returning anything when the group did not exist beforehand. I've added an if else statement to check for that and now it works like a charm.